# pkg-config giving me strange error involving gtk+-3.0 on linux mint

Tags: gtk3, linux-mint, pkg-config

So when I run:

gcc `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` -o *program-name* *code.cpp*

to compile my program against the gtk3 libraries, I get the following error:

Package 'xfixes' requires 'fixesproto >= 6.0' but version of fixesproto is 5.0

This error only shows up when trying to compile against gtk+3.0, not against
any of the other libraries with compatible  .pc files for pkg-config.

I installed gtk+3.0 libraries through synaptic package manager, so I assume
everything needed was installed, so I don't really have any idea what this
error message means, or how to fix it.

Comment: Are you trying to compile a C program or a C++ program?  I ask because of the ".cpp" extension in your example.  C++ programs using GTK3 usually use library "gtkmm-3.0" instead of "gtk-3.0".

Comment: It's the same error regardless of C or C++. In this example, I could use gtkmm-3.0 for cpp and gtk+-3.0 for C and it's the same error. In fact if I just run pkg-config --cflags gtk+3.0 on the command line without invoking gcc or g++ at all, it gives me the same error: "Package 'xfixes' requires 'fixesproto >= 6.0' but version of fixesproto is 5.0"

Comment: I don't know what might of happened on your system, but my best guess is that something got installed on your system that updated your "xfixes.pc" configuration.  I poked around on my machine and in my "xfixes.pc" file, it states "Requires: xproto fixesproto >= 5.0".  You might check the verbiage in that file on your system.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when deploying an app on Ubuntu 20.04, which was fixed by installing the latest [xorgproto library](https://lists.x.org/archives/xorg-announce/2021-April/003085.html) from sources: https://xorg.freedesktop.org/archive/individual/proto/xorgproto-2022.2.tar.xz